# Взаимодействие между компонентами Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular, frontend

У меня есть `компонент1` в котором есть массив обьектов и таблица с ними, есть `компонент2` в котором должна отображатся информация об обьекте при клике на элемент таблицы. 
Из чего состоит проблема: 
Как из `компонента1` вызвать метод `компонента2` в который передается обьект, из данных которого, инициилизируются переменные отвечающие за отображение инфы в `компонент2` ?

Компонент2

```
export class ProductStatisticsComponent implements OnInit {

  .....код....

  name : string;
  price : number;
  count : number;
  id : number;

  initStatistic(model) {
    this.name = model.name;
    this.price = model.price;
    this.count = model.count;
    this.id = model.productId;
  }

}
```

В разметке компонента2 выводится инфа в виде:

```
<label>{{name}}</label>
```

Метод Компонента1 вызываемый при клике на элемент таблицы куда передается сам обьект

```
public showStatistics(item) {
    let info = {
      name : item.name,
      price: item.price,
      count: item.count,
      id: item.productId
    }
    initStatistic(info);   

}
```

Я гуглил про @Injectable, про @Input, @Output, но либо я что-то неправильно делал, либо это не то, подскажите по этому примеру как следует поступить?

Comment: "Presentational" компоненты не должны в принципе знать о друг друге, а тем более вызывать методы друг друга, только если это не какой-то ui-kit компонент, который используется везде в приложении (например dropdown и нужно вручную вызвать метод toggle или show). Иначе 2 presentational компонента становятся жестко зацепленными. Если ты пришел к этому - значит ты что-то делаешь не так, я бы мог тебе помочь, если бы ты сделал _воспроизводимый пример_, но ты вставляешь код кусками, это не очень помогает понять вопрос.

Comment: Как это в принципе решается? Вот есть у меня компонент таблицы, я хочу получать инфу о выбраном элементе таблицы в списке который представляет другой компонент, как это решается на идеологическом уровне, абстрагируясь от кода?